# What would be the best way to capture a storm giant?

Tags: dnd-5e, campaign-development

I am building a campaign for my group and one story idea I am toying with is to have an island cult who are keeping a storm giant captive and forcing him to create bad conditions, in order to wreck small vessels so that they can then pillage them.

I'd like him to be held in some semi-aquatic caverns beneath the island as it fits well with the idea I have.

What would be a conceivable way to capture, hold and force a storm giant to do your bidding?

Comment: As asked this is a bit broad/opinion based?  You want the best way for your NPC/DM run cult to do this, or the characters?  In other words, why is it important, if these are DM run, for there to be a way beyond "make it so"  ... does it relate to how the PC's are to free the storm giant?

Comment: Idea-generation questions don't work in the Stack Exchange site format. As a rule they result in a list of ideas with [no obvious way for voters to tell which answers are better than others](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/). This would need to be revised to be about solving a specific concrete problem to be answerable in our Q&A site format. Otherwise, you may just actually want a [discussion forum](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449) instead of a Stack for this particular question.

Comment: A way in which this could be answered is to come up with a specific plan of confinement on your own and ask if there are any obvious problems with it, and if so how they can be resolved.